# Complicated SQL query for Jenkins

Tags: mysql, sql, jenkins

I am trying to create a Jenkins script using a SQL query with variables that are parameters in Jenkins. I need to use an insert using a select statement, a variable, and a static number. How can I create this query?

I have the select statement that will need to be used in the insert working:

```
SELECT uid FROM client_template.user 
WHERE TYPE = 0 AND ACTIVE = 1 
AND uid NOT IN (45,58,1331,1793,1807,2713);
```

However, I am unsure how to fit the above query into one that will work like this (Values 1234 & 1 -- correspond to did & urid):

```
INSERT INTO client_schema.user_role_roles (did, urid, uid) 
VALUES (1234, 1)
SELECT uid FROM client_template.user 
WHERE TYPE = 0 AND ACTIVE = 1 AND uid NOT IN (45,58,1331,1793,1807,2713);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't totally clear, but if you are trying to use the select statement to select the `uid` to use as the third parameter in your `INSERT` then try:

```sql
   INSERT INTO client_template.user_role_roles (did, urid, uid) 
    SELECT TOP 1 1234, 1, uid FROM client_template.user 
    WHERE TYPE = 0 AND ACTIVE = 1 AND uid NOT IN (45,58,1331,1793,1807,2713);
```

Note that your static values `1234` and `1` are simply listed as constants in your `SELECT` subquery.

Comment: I actually just realized that I asked the question incorrectly, as I will need to insert it into client_schema.user_role_roles and not template, although the select query for the uid's will be taken from client_template.user. I believe this will need a join but I am not too familiar on how to use that in my query

Answer (score 0):

You should add  the literal/constant value in the corresponding position in select

```
  INSERT INTO client_schema.user_role_roles  (did, urid, uid) 
  SELECT 1234, 1, uid 
  FROM client_template.user 
  WHERE TYPE = 0 
  AND ACTIVE = 1 
  AND uid NOT IN (45,58,1331,1793,1807,2713);
```

Comment: I actually just realized that I asked the question incorrectly, as I will need to insert it into client_schema.user_role_roles and not template, although the select query for the uid's will be taken from client_template.user. I believe this will need a join but I am not too familiar on how to use that in my query

Comment: Answer  updated   .. anyway without a proper data sample and the expected  result is not possible eval if you need  some join or a  simple insert select